# Why is it called a "multiset"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition, multisets

According to Wolfram MathWorld,

> "A set is a finite or infinite collection of objects in which order has no significance, and multiplicity is generally also ignored ..."

and

> A multiset is "A set-like object in which order is ignored, but multiplicity is explicitly significant."

In other words, both are groups of elements in which order is ignored, but whilst multiplicity is (typically) ignored in a set, multiplicity is **not** ignored but in fact the exact opposite—rather, it is **significant**—in a multiset.

But this doesn't make sense. Using the same root implies they're based off the same notion, and as *multi-* means *some multiple of*, it doesn't exactly imply some exception to that rule.

Could someone explain this to me? If *B* is the foundation of whatever *A* is, then why would *B* be the **exact opposite** of *A*?

Comment: I wouldn't say a multiset is the exact opposite of a set. It is exactly a set, but with a slight twist.

Comment: Multiset $\implies$ a set in which some elements may appear multiple (i.e., several) times. What better name would you choose for that?????

Comment: We're talking about semantics here. Maybe there is a philological stack exchange about semantical correctness of mathematical terms. Are you interested in the *content* of the notion multiset at all?

Comment: "One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand." -- Richard Feynman (said at 4:56 in his [computer heuristics lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA))

Comment: @barakmanos: I didn't think of it that way. Good point. Still, I'm just learning. You don't need to shout (please).

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: It's not about semantics, but about the mathematical reasoning behind why the term was chosen. In any case, I doubt that there is a Stack Exchange site exactly for that.

Comment: @littleO: Brilliant!

Comment: The trouble is that a multiset can have duplicates, while a set can not.  A set is more restricted. So when given a new term such as *poset*, one may ask "is this a multiset or set?"  Having the word "set",  does it also observe the same restrictions of a set having unique elements?  If yes, then back to the original question, why is "set" used in the word "multiset"?  The argument circles infinitely.  Then you ask "And what about cosets ...?"  Then you give up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way people make up words for things is far more haphazard than you seem to believe, both in math and in the broader world.  There are many examples of terms that don't really make sense when interpreted too literally.  For instance, an [antlion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antlion) bears little direct resemblance to either an ant or a lion.

That said, I strongly disagree with your characterization of a multiset as "the exact opposite" of a set.  By your criterion for "the exact opposite", any two concepts $A$ and $B$ which are not identical are "exact opposites", since you can find some property which $A$ has such that $B$ has the negation of that property.  Multisets are in fact extremely similar to sets--both sets and multisets are collections of things, and in fact every set is also a multiset.  They differ only in one small (but important!) way: any particular object can only be in a set one time, but  it can be in a multiset multiple times.  Hence the name: a multiset is something very similar to a set, except the same element can be in it multiple times.

Comment: Indeed, my thinking was quite rigid in this respect. I'm typically much less so in most other spheres of life, but I tend to think much more rigidly in mathematics since maths are very often heavily systematic. Thank you, though, for clearing this up for me. It makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of a multi-set is *not* exact opposite of set.

The fact is that in a multi-set, "the notion of importance to presence of multiplicity of same element" is exact opposite of the same notion in a set.

Every set is a multi-set, with highest multiplicity 1.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Examples) is a good example of importance of multiplicity in some natural ways.